# Processing - why does my Random Walker always tend toward the top left?

Tags: random, processing

I am currently going through Daniel Shiffman's 'The Nature Of Code', and have been playing around with one of the first exercises - a simple 'RandomWalker()'. I have implemented similar things in Java & had no trouble, however for some reason my walker always seems to go in more or less the same direction:

[RandomWalker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJHXP.png)

This happens 100% of the time. Here is my code:

```java
class Walker
{
  int x;
  int y;

  // Constructor

  Walker()
  {
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
  }

  void display()
  {
    stroke(0); // Colour
    point(x, y); // Colours one pixel in
  }

  void step()
  {
    float stepX;
    float stepY;

    stepX = random(-1, 1);
    stepY = random(-1, 1);

    x += stepX;
    y += stepY;
  }
}

Walker w;

void setup()
{
  size(640, 360);
  w = new Walker();
  background(255);
}

void draw()
{
  w.step();
  w.display();
}
```

Is this some artefact of the random function? My first thought is that it's something to do with the pseudorandom nature of the function but the textbook specifically states that this should not be noticeable, and yet this happens every single time. I was wondering if maybe there's something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` variables are both `int` types. That means that they don't have a decimal part, so any time you add or subtract from them, they are truncated. Here are some examples:

```java
int x = 1;
x = x + .5;
//1.5 is truncated, and x stays 1

int x = 1;
x = x - .5;
//.5 is truncated, and x becomes 0
```

This is why you see your `x` and `y` variables only decreasing. To fix this, just change `x` and `y` to `float` types, so they keep track of the decimals.

If you really need `x` and `y` to be `int` values, then you need `stepX` and `stepY` to also be `int` values:

```java
int stepX;
int stepY;

stepX = (int)random(-5, 5);
stepY = (int)random(-5, 5);

x += stepX;
y += stepY;
```

But you probably just want to store `x` and `y` as `float` values.

PS: I love random walkers!